# Matrices en Maxima

Tags: matrices, maxima

Necesito realizar una función que genere el siguiente tipo de matriz. Para más información, sobre este tipo de matrices, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalMatrix.html Del enlace me gustaría obtener, la L_4.

Yo tengo la definición en Python, que es el lenguaje que más conozco:

```
def pascal_upp(n):
    s = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    s[0] = [1] * n
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            s[i][j] = s[i-1][j-1] + s[i][j-1]
    return s

def pascal_low(n):
    # transpose of pascal_upp(n)
    return [list(x) for x in zip(*pascal_upp(n))]
```

También tengo la función que genera el triángulo de Pascal en Maxima

```
sjoin(v, j) := apply(sconcat, rest(join(makelist(j, length(v)), v)))$

display_pascal_triangle(n) := for i from 0 thru n do disp(sjoin(makelist(binomial(i, j), j, 0, i), " "));
```

Realmente, necesito realizar la función `pascal_low(n)` en Maxima, pero no sé cómo se pueden  implementar definiciones con matrices en este lenguaje. He hecho la definición en Python, porque veo que son lenguajes parecidos. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Lo que quiero es el que programa haga lo siguiente:

```
pascal_low(4);


                                [ 1  0  0  0 ]
                                [ 1  1  0  0 ]
(%o7)                           [ 1  2  1  0 ]
                                [ 1  3  3  1 ]
```

Comment: no es una solución como tal, pero tal vez te sirva este enlace :[Maxima Manual, 58.1 Introduction to linearalgebra](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/de/maxima_58.html) . Un saludo.